# bamboo gives panic: aborting due to terminal initialize failure when building angular app

Tags: node.js, angular, bamboo

I have an angular app that I'm building, when I run the build command `ng --aot build` directly through the terminal, it runs fine, but through the bamboo script task it gives

```
panic: aborting due to terminal initialize failure
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I tried increasing the jvm memory settings in {install_dir}/bin/setenv.sh
`JVM_MINIMUM_MEMORY` and `JVM_MAXIMUM_MEMORY` to `2048m` and `8192m` respectively..same error

**node** v13.12.0

**npm** 6.14.4

**Angular**: 9.1.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed, I was doing

`sudo npm install -g @angular/cli --force  && sudo npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular` to install angular, so I uninstalled, then renistalled using

`npm cache clean --force && npm uninstall -g angular-cli --force && sudo npm install -g @angular/cli --force && ng --help`